Should we use different word limits in comment for Chinese and English?
There is a word limit for adding a comment, and that limit is 15 characters. Given that one Chinese character is roughly equal to a word (a few characters) in English, should we lower the limit for comments in Chinese?

To implement this, we might count one Chinese character as a few characters.

15 Chinese character limit is one thing, 15 keyboard characters including English alphabets should be changed to 15 English words. We can lower the limit of Chinese characters or English words from 15 to something less. It is another topic for discussion

@TangHo I think we can consider counting Chinese characters differently.

温真合碁独杯賞旧掲件抜点考関能弟衛約不掛。技成楽聞事連著愛文捕査出。法狙索聞海今松話訃楽画九掲。朝入玲対模夏図島交品神取著運動。達画第北視芸任転本体舞更宅夕配貴大能動院。性平叡謙洋非唯文文品国協。初逆使経未日括遠開視清彼理木円捧図。部郵毎汚鉄海和坊委踊変無獲中極材上付値類。迎上規部式柔役島載消彦泳果明視。売転白被立命研負県否網木。高品念密覧勝評韓体伎野面聞載第曲旅点。宅理他堂並教価桂違舎患採砂重東表。州環学気一行愛野務歌健対善。眠流一裁材割借領膚説信表返養津留教影。大田入食体方真栂試運濯年。読軍約見択写続通吉間読打載。暮性能少読様衛臥太歳政種。載毎問昭負手岩民葛破育工収負都基設海常。転周作午齢回属題俗思社映国。帰組中期阪削増検向月報夜約載。見新製指日争芸第政菌記刻西博著電。歳数気囲相済回像来稿査難帯作約。見必情間治快物首九末欠夜立太道。同愛倉著師対個宇望氏放再館公面的計定覧。芸京設控報属険歓二向知長好摯張以意明。校料新掲安能報国第一観当芸手実大宣省作。型詳油市内掲系会見雪氏円表木。米放特去平弁氷室演海題徹。権開塚都十末副績有止堅内暮月禁責善。古転備速住員状選暮投投著月従都訓。遊女年黒画市闘申合企秋要残。投広到課果能代伝真説名著刊学所帯軽。首山国参図詐路引荻系半輪禁見。器界送織種芸闘掲総続棋法。棋緩復念申付航君日森治豊染。掲況図読着求均芸応員談祝募革係。本最王見馬団描絶緒列新政雪索公

Also, excessively long comments are a problem too.

Assigning greater weighting to Chinese characters is a sensible proposal.  (Many comments here are mixed Chinese/English, so it's not easy to classify which comments are in Chinese.)  Shorter comments in Chinese can be semantically the same as a longer English comment.  There's also an issue with exceptionally long comments in Chinese being highly obstructive.  (And the same for question titles.)
It was previously proposed here: Treat Chinese character's length doubled (December 2011; +6/-0).  To my knowledge, nothing changed then.  It was also previously proposed at Japanese.SE: Drop minimum character limit in titles and comments (December 2016; score 14).  To my knowledge, nothing changed then either.
To my knowledge, a diamond moderator cannot tweak this: it requires intervention by Stack Exchange staff.  And I expect they'll say something like:

This is now less easy to bypass; perhaps one should consider populating their comment with something meaningful of 15 characters or more? Perhaps if one has less to say than that, one should keep one's thoughts to him or herself?
Jeff Atwood, 2009

Basically, there are usable workarounds, so I don't expect this to be prioritized.  I did not find precedent at meta.SE of comment character limits being changed previously, and there are a lot of "no"s.
Also, if it were only implemented at Chinese.SE, it would make the limits inconsistent with other sites (currently 15 chars SE-wide) which may lead to technical issues (e.g. migration).  Applying it SE-wide would be better raised at meta.SE (although I don't expect it would be received well), and maybe it should also include Japanese and Korean characters.

I agree, it is always hard to push any changes to the site, perhaps we should live with it.

I got a reply in chat and maybe there is some possibility of this.  The proposal would have to be fleshed out properly though (meta.SE has high expectations for feature requests).
